# how to find the integral of a rational logarithmic function

Tags: integration, logarithms, rational-functions

I can't seem to figure this one out,

it is:

$$\int\frac{\ln(x)}xdx $$

I substituted $u$ for $\ln(x)$,  so $u = \ln(x)$  and $du = \frac1x dx$

then to find $x$ in terms of $u$:   $e^u = x$

so I get

$$\int\frac{u}{e^{u^2}}du$$

from here I can't figure out where to go,  I have tried playing around with the numbers 
but after a few hours I figured I'd ask someone here.

I sense that I must somehow get it to the form $$\int\frac1xdx,$$  but i an not sure how to get a $1$ in the numerator.

Comment: There's no need to do $e^u=x$, and somehow it led you to the wrong integral in terms of $u$. Try that substitution again.

Comment: Thank you,  my substitution was completely wrong.  For some reason I kept forgetting to balance out 1/x dx by putting a x in the numerator before the substitution.  However I don't understand why I don't need to do e^u=x ?   because the intermediate equation Integral(xu/x)du would not be correct?

Comment: I think @5xum has answered that in the answer.

Comment: $e^u=x$ is not wrong, you just don't need to replace any $x$-s with $u$-s anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your replacement of variables is wrong. Since $u=\ln x$, you get
$$\int\ln x \cdot \frac{1}{x}dx$$
in which you replace $\ln x$ with $u$ and $\frac1x dx$ with $du$. What you get does not contain any $e^u$ or $e^{u^2}$.

Comment: Thank you,  you are correct, I messed up on the substitution.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $\frac 1 x$ is the derivation of  $\log x$ so your integral has the form
$$\int f(x)f'(x)dx$$
can you take it from here?

Comment: Integration by parts, I should have mentioned that we haven't got to that section,  so I am assuming that I am supposed to solve it by other means.  Thank you for the fine suggestion though!

Comment: This isn't an integration by parts! What's the derivative of 
$$(f(x))^2\;?$$

Comment: 2f(x)*D(f(x)). chain rule